# Call to a member function getQuote() Error

Tags: php, error

Out of no where I am receiving this error within my one page checkout. When I went check the PHP file this file was not in the folder. I uploaded a new file and I am still getting this error. Does anyone one what this error can be?

Fatal error: Call to a member function getQuote() on a non-object in /home/sitename/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php on line 195

Comment: Add your controller code here. Also add exact magento version.